# Android and Arduino Bluetooth communication. How to indicate that current data transaction is over?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on a project which requires the Android phone sending and receiving Bluetooth data. Arduino always sends integer values to the Android phone and I was wondering how can I let Android phone know that the current data transaction is over. Here is how I handle receiving the data in Android.

```
//Reads the arriving bluetooth data from Arduino and forwards it to other activities
//Note: Arriving BT data is in ASCII values and this class converts it to its integer
//Values before sending it.
private class btDataListener extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {
    List<Integer> BtMessage = new ArrayList<>();
    while(isBtConnected) {
      try {
        if(mmInStream != null) {
          while(btSocket.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
            BtMessage.add(btSocket.getInputStream().read());
          }
          if(BtMessage.size() > 0) {
            //Send received message to Activities
            Intent intent = new Intent("my-integer");
            intent.putExtra("message", BtMessageToInt(BtMessage));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
            BtMessage.clear();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG,"btCommunicationService: btDataListener: ERROR:: " + e);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

They won't be regarded as part of the same message. Also, I am quite new to Android development, so if my method is not good to begin with, please advise where can I read about how to handle this situation. Thank you.

Comment: You can either close the socket or write some end of message (EOM)  string  to indicate a message is over

Comment: Hmm, I see. Is there an easy way to extract integers or full strings from the socket by the way? It seems like Bluetooth always receives ASCII characters in each byte.

Comment: The String constructor accepts byte array. You can parse a String object into an int.

Comment: I see, but what will happen if I send 2 strings one after another? How would Android know where the first one ended and the second one began? Should I use some special character to indicate the end of the message or the /0 at the end of the string will do that for me?

Comment: It won't do that for you, no. You'll have to manually detect that as part of your "message handling" code

Comment: Got it. Thanks, cricket, I was able to use * and | symbols as the start of a message and end of a message in order to make sure that arrived messages are in complete form. It works just fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to post your code as an answer below so others may find your solution useful

Answer (score 0):

So this is my current solution. I did not unit test the function yet, but the goal is to make sure that I get the data from the input stream into a string. Also, the function makes sure that start and end symbols are present and are in correct format. If not, that message is ignored. Future work should probably implement a mechanism to recover from this via Ack mechanism. I use * as a starting symbol for the message and | as an ending symbol.

```
private class btDataListener extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
            String completeMessage = "";
            String startSymbol = "*";
            String endSymbol = "|";
            while(isBtConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(mmInStream != null)
                    {

                        while(btSocket.getInputStream().available() > 0 || incomingData.length() != 0)
                        {
                            if(btSocket.getInputStream().available() > 0)
                            {
                                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                                incomingData = incomingData + new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                            }

                            //here we are parsing the incomingData string and if it contains
                            //a full message(meaning it have starting symbol * and ending symbol | in correct places),
                            //We extract the coomplete message and pass it on to activities
                            //If we find mistakes such as unmatched start symbols for end symbols and so on,
                            //We clean the  incomingData from bad strings.

                            int start = incomingData.indexOf(startSymbol);
                            int end = incomingData.indexOf(endSymbol);
                            int extraStartSymbol = incomingData.substring(start+1, incomingData.length()).indexOf(startSymbol);

                            if(start == -1 && end != -1)
                            {
                                incomingData = incomingData.substring(end + 1, incomingData.length());
                            }
                            else if(start != -1 && end != -1 && start > end)
                            {
                                incomingData = incomingData.substring(start, incomingData.length());
                            }
                            else if(start != -1 && end != -1 && (extraStartSymbol != -1 && extraStartSymbol < end))
                            {
                                incomingData = incomingData.substring(extraStartSymbol + 1, incomingData.length());
                            }
                            else if(start != -1 && end != -1)
                            {
                                completeMessage = incomingData.substring(start+1,end);
                                incomingData = incomingData.substring(end + 1,incomingData.length());
                            }

                            if(!completeMessage.equals(""))
                            {
                                //Send received message in int form to Activities
                                Intent intent = new Intent("my-integer");
                                intent.putExtra("message", Integer.parseInt(completeMessage));
                                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

                                completeMessage = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG,"btCommunicationService: btDataListener: ERROR:: " + e);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```